# How to get host info (CPU utilisation) from within a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm running a node.js app within a docker container (because I can't install node on our machines). My app uses the systeminformation package to get cpu utilisation, but this is cpu utilisation of the docker container. I want the CPU utilisation of a process running on the host.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PID namespace of the host with the `--pid=host` option to `docker run`.

From the manpage:

> ```
>    --pid=""
>       Set the PID mode for the container
>       Default is to create a private PID namespace for the container
>                                   'container:<name|id>': join another container's PID namespace
>                                   'host': use the host's PID namespace for the container. Note: the host mode gives the container
> ```
>
> full access to local PID and is therefore considered insecure.